# stored dates in unixtime (INT 10) check interval

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp

I have a table to store data for car rental purposes (reservations awaiting response). The is a field called 'initiated_datime' (INT, 10) where the initiated datime of the reservation is stored (I already know that INT 10 is not the most efficient way, 2038 etc.).

I would like to view reservations awaiting response more than 24 hours for further reporting...

The following examples work for me

```
SELECT * FROM rentals WHERE rental_flag = 1 AND '".$cur_datetime_unixtime."' >(initiated_datime + 86400) ... WHERE $cur_datetime_unixtime is created in php
```

AND

```
SELECT * FROM rentals WHERE rental_flag = 1 AND unix_timestamp(now()) > (initiated_datime + 86400)
```

is there any way to change (initiated_datime + 86400) with a more efficient code? like: unix_timestamp(initiated_datime + 1 day interval)?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in the general case; but in this instance, that inequality is equivalent to:

```
SELECT * FROM rentals WHERE rental_flag = 1 
AND unix_timestamp(now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) > initiated_datime
```

Comment: thank you for your answer... can you please explain your answer? unix_timestamp(now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) > initiated_datime equals to initiated_datime + 1day > initiated_datime ?

Comment: You're comparing the current timestamp to `initiated_datime` plus 86400 seconds (== 1 day).  That the same as comparing "current timestamp, 1 day ago" to `initiated_datime` directly.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to fix this is to change your columns to a `datetime`. You can than easily use [date/time](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) functions to manipulate your filter.